# Необходимо записать в список xCords координату черепашки по x, а в yCords — по y

Tags: python, turtle

Необходимо записать в список xCords координату черепашки по x, а в yCords — по y. Поскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `xCords = x`, `yCords = y`

Comment: Всм, это и весь ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял то так:

```
xcords = [] 
ycords = [] 

xcords.append(turtle.xcor())
ycords.append(turtle.ycor())
```